# MediaBrowserServiceCompat methods

Tags: android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-browser, android-service-binding, android-mediasession

How do I access the public methods that I have defined (not the overridden ones) in the MediaBrowserServiceCompat from an activity?

Earlier I had used just the service, so I could bind it with the activity class and then access the methods easily.

Now since no binder is returned (onBind is not overriden in mediaBrowserService) , how can that be done?

(I have also read from ianblake's blog that mediaBrowserService is automatically bound...is that useful here?)

Answer (score 2):

This was the top-ranked Google search result but this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50104541/3018586) actually provides the step to accomplish what is needed.

Edit:
Steps copied from the link above

1. Create a MediaControllerCompat from your MediaBrowserCompat instance, following the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowser-client#customize-mediabrowser-connectioncallback)
2. Call [sendCommand](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html#sendCommand(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.ResultReceiver)), passing in a command String which uniquely identifies your command (say, doMagic), any parameters you wish to pass to the method, and a ResultReceiver if you want a return value.
3. In the MediaSessionCompat.Callback registered with your MediaBrowserServiceCompat, override [onCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.Callback#onCommand%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.ResultReceiver%29) and handle the command (say, by calling doMagic).

Comment: While this link might provide the right answer, it is always advised to provide some explanation and examples relevant to the question asked. Please check here on how to structure a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer