# How to access instance of MediaBrowserServiceCompat service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-support-library, android-service-binding

I'm surprisingly struggling to get hold of the instance of a service which is derived from `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`.

For a typical service, to achieve that, a local binder is used

```
class MyService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
  class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
      return MyService.this;
    }

  private final MyBinder binder = new MyBinder();

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
  }

  public void doMagic() { // <-- How to call this from activity?
    // ...
  }
}

// At the activity, for example, this binder is retrieved through 
// `onServiceConnected()`, typecast to `MyBinder` and thus 
// `getService()` gets us the service instance.
```

However, this does not work for the service derived from `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`.

When I try to provide local binder, as shown above, service crashed since `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` expects its own custom binder with additional functionality. Here is the crash stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Binder.queryLocalInterface(Binder.java:254)
    at android.service.media.IMediaBrowserService$Stub.asInterface(IMediaBrowserService.java:31)
    at android.media.browse.MediaBrowser$MediaServiceConnection.onServiceConnected(MediaBrowser.java:793)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1223)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1240)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

I tried wrapping the binder from `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` super class, like below, but still it wouldn't work.

```
class MyService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
  class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public MyService getService() {
      return MyService.this;
    }

  private final WrappingBinder<MyService> binder;

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (binder == null) {
      binder = new WrappingBinder(super.onBind(intent));
    }

    return binder;
  }

  public void doMagic() { // <-- How to call this from activity or elsewhere?
    // ...
  }
}
```

So wondering what is the approach to follow to access the instance of MediaBrowserServiceCompat service?

To be clear, Playback functionality is working fine for me. The question is about how to get a reference to the service, so that I can make calls to my custom public methods on that service.

Comment: `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` is a Service . To create one `class MyService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat` Follow [This](https://medium.com/google-developers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90). it may help .

Comment: I followed that. Playback functionality is working fine for me. The question is about how to get a reference to the service, so that I can make calls to my custom public methods on that service.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you discovered, `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` is already a bound service - you cannot and should not override `onBind()`.

Instead, you must connect to your `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` with a `MediaBrowserCompat` as per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowser-client#connect-to-mediabrowserservice). Once connected, you can trigger custom methods, like `doMagic` by:

1. Create a `MediaControllerCompat` from your `MediaBrowserCompat` instance, following [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowser-client#customize-mediabrowser-connectioncallback)
2. Call 
   [`sendCommand`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html#sendCommand(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.ResultReceiver)), passing in a `command` String which uniquely identifies your command (say, `doMagic`), any parameters you wish to pass to the method, and a `ResultReceiver` if you want a return value.
3. In the `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` registered with your `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`, override [onCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.Callback#onCommand%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.ResultReceiver%29) and handle the command (say, by calling `doMagic`).

An example of this approach was offered in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@ianhlake/dont-try-to-access-the-mediaplayer-directly-in-your-ui-or-create-another-binding-59ad690ab81)

Comment: Dear ianhanniballake, how can I notify UI update from MediaBrowserServiceCompat, in my case, player file need download to local before play, how can I notify activity show/hide loading. Thanks

Comment: @hai - sounds like you should take a look at the `EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS` constant and it's related methods. You can also send custom actions from your service to all connected MediaBrowserCompat via the `sendSessionEvent` API on the MediaBrowserServiceCompat

Comment: Thank you so much, it's what I looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution (for a quick fix, not recommend):

```
private final MyBinder myBinder = new MyBinder();
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getBooleanExtra("is_binding", false)) {
        return myBinder;
    }
    return super.onBind(intent);
}

// Bind service in your activity:

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPlaybackService.class);
intent.putExtra("is_binding", true);

bindService(intent, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```